# Update Query for Column Value change Sequentially

Tags: sql, database, db2, ibm-midrange

I have the following data in a Physical file:

```
   KFIELD     KVALUE

   C18R01     ABCD
   C18R01     ABCD
   C18R02     ABCD
   C18R02     ABCD
   C18R03     ABCD
    .
    .
   C18R39     ABCD
```

I would now like to have the KFIELD column updated to C38R01,C38R01, C38R02 and so on

I am using DB2 or SQL over iSeries, please help in updating the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `REPLACE` function as below

```
update physical
set KFIELD = REPLACE(KFIELD,'C18R', 'C38R')
```

Comment: Awesome!Thanks for the prompt response

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple update statement using `replace()`:

```
update Physical
    set kfield = replace(kfield, 'C18R', 'C38R')
```